# Microsoft Sign-In for ASP.NET MVC 5 web role

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, azure, microsoft-account

I have created Azure cloud service and in this cloud service I have a web role serving as a MVC web application. I followed [this](http://www.benday.com/2014/02/25/walkthrough-asp-net-mvc-identity-with-microsoft-account-authentication/) tutorial to use Microsoft account as the external authentication. When I try with the localhost it works perfectly. However, after I deploy the cloud service, I changed the redirect URL to the site url which is http://109e199cf5864b50ab25ac839f8c151d.cloudapp.net/. But this doesn't work. I can reach the authorization part, but after I login with the Microsoft account I got Error Message: An error occurred while processing your request. What should I do to make it work?

UPDATE:
I tried to remove the [Authorize] tag in my controller so that I don't need to login to see the view. After I deployed again, I got the Error Message directly!!
I didn't login at all! I checked the code this Error Message is actually the Error view from the template in the Shared folder. But there is no change of the code to return me this Error view! What I am missing with the deployment here?

Answer (score 0):

In the comments of the blog post you referenced, the author (Ben Day) said there was an update to the redirect URI.

> With the latest version of the ASP.NET Identity code, the redirect uri is a different value. So on account.live.com, the redirect url value for your app is now going to be “http://myapp-url/signin-microsoft”.

You may want to check that you have the correct values here.

Comment: Yes, the redirect url is correct. And this uredirect url works with local host but after I deployed I changed the local host with the assigned domain name, that doesn't work.